# ¿Por qué los números aleatorios se repiten al llamar a .Next()?

Tags: c#, random

Buen día!

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en C# y estoy haciendo un programa que me de el resultado de dos dados.

Entonces hago una clase Dado y creo dos objetos dado1 y dado2 y llamo a un metodo que me calcule un numero al azar.

El problema que siempre me calcula los dos dados iguales.

Así escribi la clase Dado:

```
class Dado
{
        private int dado;
        private Random aleatorio = new Random();

        public Dado()
        {
          dado = 0; 
        }

        public int Valor()
        {                    
            dado = aleatorio.Next(1, 7);
            return dado;           
        }                

}
```

y desde el formulario creo los dos objetos dado1 y dado2, y dentro de un boton "lanzo" los dados.

```
private Dado dado1, dado2;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dado1 = new Dado();
    dado2 = new Dado();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Dado 1 salio: " + Convert.ToString(dado1.Valor()) + " y Dado 2 salio: " + Convert.ToString(dado2.Valor());      
}
```

Pero siempre que apreto el boton los dos dados caen en el mismo número, van cambiando pero caen igual.
Ejemplo:

Primera tirada dado1 = 2 y dado2 = 2
Segunda tirada dado1 = 5 y dado2 = 5
tercera tirada dado1 = 3 y dado2 = 3

es como si cuando el objeto dado2 llama al metodo Valor no funcionara.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En estos casos, siempre es útil mirar la documentación:
[Random()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Aquí te dice:

> El valor de inicialización predeterminado se deriva del reloj del sistema y tiene una resolución finita. Como resultado, diferentes Random objetos que se crean en estrecha sucesión mediante una llamada al constructor predeterminado tendrán valores de inicialización predeterminados idénticos y, por consiguiente, generarán conjuntos idénticos de números aleatorios

Una pequeña aclaración; los ordenadores son muy malos para generar verdaderos valores aleatorios. Lo que se llama "aleatorio" suele ser en realidad **pseudoaleatorio**; en función de un número inicial (*semilla*) se usan unas fórmulas para obtener los siguientes.

Es decir, un objeto creado por `Random()` te devolverá una serie de valores en función del momento en que se crea. Si creas dos objetos con el mismo valor inicial (=al mismo tiempo, o casi), la serie de valores será idéntica.

Solución: hay dos posibles soluciones:

- Hacer un pequeña pausa en la ejecución para que pase al menos 1ms.
- Hacer que se inicialicen los dos números de forma diferente; por ejemplo

  Añadir constructor:

  ```
  public Dado(int semilla) {
     this.aleatorio = new Random(semilla);
  }
  ```

  y al crearlos

  ```
  Random inicializador = new Random();
  Dado dado1 = new Dado(inicializador.Next());
  Dado dado2 = new Dado(inicializador.Next());
  ```

  Esto hace que cada dado tenga una semilla diferente, asegurando que las secuencias no serán iguales.

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Repensando un poco, la solución de arriba tiene un pequeño problema: no hay ninguna garantía de que dos números aleatorios consecutivos no sean iguales; si bien la probabilidad es minúscula (`1 / (2 ^ 32)`, o `1 entre 4.294.967.296`), no es 0. Y si se da ese improbable caso<sup>1</sup>, entonces los dados volverán a sacar los mismos números (de nuevo, menos de una vez cada cuatro mil millones de ejecuciones del programa).

Así que sería mejor esta variación:

```
Random inicializador = new Random();
Int32 semilla = inicializador.Next();
Dado dado1 = new Dado(semilla);
Dado dado2 = new Dado(semilla + 1);
```

También, como indiqué en un comentario, otra opción sería crear un único objeto dado y simplemente ejecutarlo más veces; en la vida real se suelen usar varios para hacer las tiradas más rápidas pero eso en un programa no es problema. Así:

```
label1.Text = "Dado 1 salio: " + Convert.ToString(dado.Valor()) + " y Dado 2 salio: " + Convert.ToString(dado.Valor());
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Para que nos hagamos una idea, la posibilidad de que tirando dos dados perfectos 10 veces, en cada tirada los dados saquen el mismo valor es de `1 entre 6 ^ 10` ó `1 entre 60.466.176`, que es mucho mayor que la probabilidad de que se dé este fallo.

Comment: La solución de Carlos Muñoz también es válida.

Answer (score 2):

Haz que la propiedad `aleatorio` sea `static`

```
class Dado
{
    private int dado;
    private static Random aleatorio = new Random();

    public int Valor()
    {                    
        dado = aleatorio.Next(1, 7);
        return dado;           
    }                
}
```

La razón es que al hacer que el campo `aleatorio` sea  `static` ambas instancias comparten el mismo objeto `Random`. De esta manera cada vez que se llame a Valor se obtendrá un número aleatorio diferente al anterior.

La clase Random no genera números aleatorios realmente sino que estos se basan en una semilla (`seed`), al no pasarle como parámetro el valor de seed se genera uno en base a la fecha actual.

Si se crean dos instancias de la clase `Random` de manera consecutiva el seed se está inicializando al mismo valor por lo que las dos instancias generarán los mismos "números aleatorios"

Comment: Lo cual, bien pensado, lleva a la siguiente optimización... en la práctica es lo mismo lanzar dos dados que lanzar un dado dos veces, y sólo se necesita una única instancia de `Dado`.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar el siguiente código en el clic del botón y veras que es bastante bueno.

```
Random dado1 = new Random();
int result1 = dado1.Next(1,6);

Random dado2 = new Random();
int result2 = dado2.Next(result1, 6);

label1.Text = "Dado 1 -> " + result1 + " Dado 2 -> " + result2;
```

Comment: Depende que tan rápido se ejecute el `new Random()` este código tiene el mismo problema

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene ningún sentido. Dejando aparte que no soluciona el problema de usar la misma semilla, con esto el valor de las dos tiradas no es independiente.