# C#: Método de generar claves devuelve la misma información

Tags: c#

Buen día, tengo una función para generar claves aleatorias y funciona bien.

```
        public string CreatePassword(int length)
    {
        string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }
```

Sin embargo, cuando llamo a la función dos veces desde una misma función obtengo la misma clave, cuando deberían ser distintas.

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lusuario = CreatePassword(12);
        string lclave = CreatePassword(12);
        tbUsuario.Text = lusuario;
        tbClave.Text = lclave;
    }
```

Obteniendo este resultado:

[image: Imagen que muestra misma clave y usuario]

Comment: No voto para cerrar por duplicado porque ya hay buenas respuestas, pero aquí está https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77056/por-qu%c3%a9-los-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-se-repiten-al-llamar-a-next/77061#77061

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La clase `Random` no es un verdadero generador de números aleatorios. Es un generador `pseudo-aleatorio` . Cualquier instancia de `Random` tiene una cierta cantidad de estados, y cuando se llama `Next(o NextDouble o NextBytes)`  puede retornar datos que parecen ser al azar.

Entonces, ¿ Cuál es el Problema?

Está usando una nueva instancia de `Random` en cada llamada al método. El constructor sin parámetros para `Random` toma la fecha y la hora actuales como la semilla, y generalmente se puede ejecutar una buena cantidad de código antes de que el temporizador interno determine que la fecha y la hora actuales han cambiado. Por lo tanto, estamos usando la misma semilla repetidamente y obteniendo los mismos resultados siempre.

Para ejemplificar esto , puede aplicar un `Sleep(1000)` *(solo para el ejemplo)* entre las llamadas a las funciones

```
string lusuario = CreatePassword(12);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
string lclave = CreatePassword(12);
```

Genera claves diferentes ya que la semilla será diferente. *(Fecha y Hora)*

Como solución ya recibiste una respuesta, otra sería declarar la variable `Random` a nivel de clase y eliminarla del método `CreatePassword` , además podría declarar su String `valid` a nivel de clase.

```
private readonly string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Y su método quedaría

```
public string CreatePassword(int length){
  StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(); 
  while (0 < length--)
  {
    res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
    return res.ToString();
   }
 }
```

> [Referencia , Random numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx)

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta funciona y es satisfactoria. Entiendo que al poner una semilla distinta genera un aleatorio distinto; sin embargo, aún no logro comprender el porqué también funciona si declaro la variable "rnd" a nivel de clase.

Comment: Porque si la declaras a nivel de clase, solo se pone la semilla en la primer llamada, y despues solo devuelve el proximo aleatorio, no reinicia el algoritmo de creacion.

Comment: Interesante y muy satisfactorio. Gracias por su apoyo, son de lo mejor. Saludos.

Comment: @LCrack como menciona el comentario anterior , no se vuelve a la crear la instancia como en su método anterior ,ni a asignar una nueva semilla para el `pseudaleatorio`, simplemente ejecuta el `Next` que devolverá un nuevo pseudoaleatorio

Answer (score 10):

La funcion random no es perfecta. Si no le pones una semilla, en realidad siempre tira los mismos numeros.
Para colmo, como la estas inicializando cada vez que lo llamas, vuelve al principio del algoritmo.

Para agregarle una semilla, debes llamarla de la siguiente manera

```
Random rnd = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
```

Este es un ejemplo directo de la MSDN, la cual aclara que el algoritmo para generarlos es matematico y la funcion es pseudo aleatoria.

Prueba agregando algo asi, y deberian salirte siempre claves distintas.

[Enlace a la MSDN en ingles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: En algunas ejecuciones del sistema, la primera vez que hago clic en el botón generar me aparecen dos claves distintas, pero para las próximas veces se replica la misma clave. Entiendo que al asignarse una semilla diferente el valor debe ser distinto pero no está funcionado de esa manera.

Comment: Esto pasa porque entre las llamadas en realidad no hay tiempo de espera, y como el codigo ya quedo cacheado de la primera llamada, el tiempo en la segunda ejecucion se reduce al minimo. Como respuesta vale el sleep que te puso joel entre las llamadas, aunque podria ser mas chico tambien, eso tendras que probarlo a ver que te conviene.

Answer (score 1):

la clase `Random` toma como semilla el reloj de la CPU por lo que genera números pseudo-aleatorios. 
Te recomiendo uses la clase [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider), que usa como generador de semilla varios elementos del Sistema Operativo para generar números totalmente aleatorios.
Ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleApp1.Classes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i< 100;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CreatePassword(i));
            } 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static string CreatePassword(int length)
        {
            const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] uintBuffer = new byte[sizeof(uint)];

                while (length-- > 0)
                {
                    rng.GetBytes(uintBuffer);
                    uint num = BitConverter.ToUInt32(uintBuffer, 0);
                    res.Append(valid[(int)(num % (uint)valid.Length)]);
                }
            }

            return res.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```