# Llenar arreglo bidimensional con la diagonal principal con -1

Tags: c#

Tengo una matriz de 5 x 5 lo cual la lleno con números aleatorios que estén entre 1 y 9 pero quisiera que la diagonal principal de la matriz se llene solo con (-1)

Comment: Una matriz no es un arreglo unidimensional

Comment: Si lo siento no me percate de ese error son bidimensionales

Comment: Lo que pides es algo muy sencillo.Necesitamos ver que has intentado para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Necesito de mucha ayuda como calcular la matriz adjunta de una matriz nxn

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar de este modo:

```
 mat = new int[5,5];
 Random rnd = new Random();

 for(int f = 0; f < 5; f++) 
 {
     for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++) 
     {
         if(f == c){

                mat[f, c] = -1;

          }else{

                mat[f, c] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Random rnd = new Random(); si haces esto, la matriz siempre se va a llenar de la misma forma. ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/134480/324. En general siempre se espera que quien pregunta haya intentado aunque sea algo ;)

Comment: Como bien dice @gbianchi,hay que intentar no responder estas preguntas (que posiblemente tengan que ver con algun trabajo escolar) sin ver que el OP ha intentado algo. Y como te ha explicado también, el `Random rnd = new Random;` debe ir fuera del bucle.