# Error al generar números aleatorios C#

Tags: c#

He creado un programa de consola que genera números aleatorios entre el 0 y el 36 y dependiendo del numero que genere aumenta en uno el valor de la casilla con el mismo numero de una Array. Aquí mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _13.Ruleta_1000_veces
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] celda = new int[37];

            for (int tiradas = 0; tiradas < 1000; tiradas++)
            {
                Random generator = new Random();
                int numeroaleatorio = generator.Next(0, 37);

                Console.WriteLine(numeroaleatorio);

                celda[numeroaleatorio] += 1;
            }

            for (int impresion = 0; impresion < celda.Length; impresion++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Posición " + impresion + ": " + celda[impresion] + " veces");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando inicio el programa me sale que el numero aleatorio ha tenido el mismo valor las 1000 veces. Para comprobar si era un error de programación he ido mirando paso a paso lo que pasaba. Lo extraño es que si lo hago paso a paso funciona perfectamente.

Con el código que he puesto esto ya no pasa porque al poner la linea *Console.WriteLine(numeroaleatorio);* esto se ha solucionado parcialmente, ahora no me salen todos los numero iguales pero me salen muchos seguidos iguales.

Mi hipótesis es que no le dejo el tiempo suficiente al programa para hacer el numero aleatorio y solo le da tiempo a hacer unos pocos. He llegado a esta conclusión ya que si hago 100000 tiradas puedo ver que sale el mismo numero aleatorio varias veces seguidas. Lo que no entiendo es la razón, ¿no se supone que el programa no pasa de linea si no ha calculado lo que hay en la esta esta? ¿Alguna forma de arreglarlo?

Comment: Lo he leído y creo que no es exactamente lo mismo. Ha mi el numero se me repite muchas veces. Puede ser que la respuesta sea muy parecida o incluso la misma. Soy principiante así que no se mucho.

Comment: Estás creando el `Random` dentro del bucle, con el mismo valor de semilla/seed (la hora del sistema). Así que, con el mismo valor de semilla, la serie de números es la misma y el primer número de la secuencia (que es el único que solicitas) es el mismo. Crea el `Random` una sola vez, fuera del bucle.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, me ha funcionado.

Comment: Y tambien es un duplicado de esta> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134480/c-m%c3%a9todo-de-generar-claves-devuelve-la-misma-informaci%c3%b3n/134484#134484

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] celda = new int[37];
        Random generator = new Random();

        for (int tiradas = 0; tiradas < 1000; tiradas++)
        {
            int numeroaleatorio = generator.Next(0, 37);

            Console.WriteLine(numeroaleatorio);

            celda[numeroaleatorio] += 1;
        }

        for (int impresion = 0; impresion < celda.Length; impresion++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Posición " + impresion + ": " + celda[impresion] + " veces");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```