# Ayuda con una función

Tags: c#, if, while, random

tengo un problema, estoy realizando una función la cual genera una de un numero fijo un numero aleatorio el cual debe mostrar por pantalla el numero aleatorio seguido del resultado ya restado y a medida que se presiona una tecla continué restando hasta 0, mi problema es que no sé por que me me indica el numero aleatorio correctamente, pero al realizar la resta me resta el doble de lo que me muestra en pantalla, dejaré imagen con el código.

Primera Img
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segunda Img
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

tercera IMG[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

Cuarta IMG
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][4]][4]

---

si, ningún problema , con tal de que me puedan ayudar; La idea del còdigo es que cuando el valor de vida que sin 1650 sea 0 deje de mostrar numeracion...pero el codigo continua igual.tambien si saco del calculo una resta, un aleatorio no continua o me muestra el mismo numero del daño del daño hecho o se resetea restando constantemente a 1560 en vez del resultado de la resta anterior... no se si me explico bien.

Edito el código 24/09/2018 a las 6:16 chile.

```
        public void Daño_Aleatorio_Melee_a_Enemigo()
    {

        int semilla = (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int dmax = DañoMaxMelee();
        int dmin = DañoMinMeleeDistance();
        int dmgfinal = rnd.Next(dmin, dmax);
        int vida = VidaE - dmgfinal;

        while (VidaE != 0)
        {
            if (vida > 0) {

                Random rnd2 = new Random();                    
                int dmgfinal2 = rnd.Next(dmin, dmax);
                vida = vida - dmgfinal2;

                Console.WriteLine("el daño es de " + dmgfinal2 + " La vida del enemigo  es de " + vida);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (vida <=0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Enemigo eliminado");
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;


            }

        }
```

Ahora solo muestra el primer daño que parece ser restado x2  las demás restas las comprobé y son correctas

adjunto resultado por consola:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo puedo ver en tu código;
Estas usando la variable "resta" en la que restas dos veces, una vez restas **dmgfinal** y después en el segundo bucle "while" le restas a esa variable el **dmgfinal2**.
No se si te ayudo necesitaría ver mas código para estar seguro. Un saludo.

Comment: Si en vez de imagenes, copias el código utilizando el sniper de código podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Deberias editar el post y colocar en vez  de imágenes código

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios problemas de lógica, pero el primer problema que tienes es este

```
while (resta != 0)
```

En su lugar usa

```
while (resta > 0)
```

Eso aplica **para ambos bucles**, ya que su un enemigo llega a tener energía negativa se arruinaría el sentido de lo que quieres hacer, por eso deberías solo hacer las operaciones cuando los enemigos aun tengan energía, es decir cuando la energía sea mayor a 0, no igual a 0 ni menor a 0.

Si tu propósito es no manejar energía negativa lo cual parece bastante lógico, no deberías manejar tipo de dato `int` sino `uint`.

Estas variables no requieren inicializarce dentor de cada bucle asi que dejalas por fuera de los bucles.

```
    int dmax = DañoMaxDistance();
    int dmin = DañoMinMeleeDistance();
    Random rnd = new Random();
```

De igual forma tampoco necesitas dos objetos `Random` diferentes, según veo con uno es suficiente, y si requieres dos de todas maneras inicilizalos por fuera del bucle únicamente.

Comment: Si bién seguí lo que me dijiste primero gracias por la atencion a este post, pero ahora tengo un problema, el daño no se hace variable, toma solo el primero y luego se repite el mismo numero y al realizar la primera resta  se resta x2 , las demás están OK. que puede ser?

Comment: Saca la creación del objeto Random del bucle

Comment: @ChristianAndresHyuden mira por favor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/77056/324 y tambien otras preguntas similares. Los numeros aleatorios no son aleatorios realmente.

Comment: quizas deba crear una semilla como lo dice en este blog?
http://www.elguille.info/NET/dotnet/random_Next.aspx#zip

Comment: Revisando todo tu código crea el Random incluso por fuera de la función puede ser como un objeto estático y verás cómo se soluciona tu problema tu problema no es la semilla en este caso