# resultado repetitivo

Tags: c#

alguien tiene idea de lo que pasa en mi código?, lo que quiero hacer son cadenas random, mi primer for funciona me hace un random de numeros y letras pero lo que quiero hacer es que mi ciclo for se repita dos veces dandome diferentes resultados, tengo este codigo, y en mi listbox si me muestra los dos resultados pero se me repiten, y lo que busco que sea diferente. mi texbox lo unico que hace es dar el valor de los numeros de caracteres que quiero que tenga mi resultado, mi cantidad es el numero de resultados diferentes que quiero obtener mas se me repite.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Random obj = new Random();
  string posibles = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
  int longitud = posibles.Length;
  int cantidad = 2;
  char letra;
  int longitudnuevacadena = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
  string nuevacadena = "";

  for (int n = 0; n < longitudnuevacadena; n++)
  {
    letra = posibles[obj.Next(longitud)];
    nuevacadena += letra.ToString();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add(nuevacadena);
  }
}
```

Comment: Saca `Random obj = new Random();` del método y ponlo a nivel de clase. Los numeros aleatorios en computación no son realmente aleatorios, si no pseudo aleatorios. No se si esto ya se ha contestado con anterioridad, si no es asi y tengo luego tiempo te amplio con una respuesta.

Comment: Puedes leer tambien [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/77056/15301) donde se explica un poco mas el problema que tienes.