# (c#) convertir un grupo de métodos a int/string

Tags: c#

Estoy aprendiendo c# y estaba escribiendo un ''simple'' programa de pelea de texto, con daño aleatorio, etc. para poder practicar lo que he aprendido en c#. El problema es que al hacer mi 'generador de daños aleatorio se reste de la 'vida del enemigo'  me tira el error ''cs0019  el operador - no se puede aplicar a operadores de tipo int y grupo de métodos''. intente usar el Convert.ToInt32 pero me tira error "cs1503 no se puede convertir de grupo de "metodos a object". ¿hay alguna forma de solucionar?

Aquí todo el código que estoy usando:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int opcion;
            int Vida = 100;
            int Nvida = 100;
           

            Console.WriteLine("un enemigo avanza hacia ti, que haces? ");

            while (Vida != 0 || Nvida != 0)
            {





                Console.WriteLine("Tu vida: " + Vida + "vida del enemigo: " + Nvida);
                Console.WriteLine("1) atacas \n2) te defiendes ");
                opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());








                switch (opcion)
                {

                    case 1:
                        int daño = 0;

                        //Esto lo lee bien Console.WriteLine(rdanom(0));

                        Nvida = Nvida - rdanom;


                        // intento de transformarlo a int Console.WriteLine("has atacado y le has quitado "+ Convert.ToInt32(rdanom) + " de vida al enemigo");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        

                        Console.Clear();
                        opcion = 0;
                        break;
                    case 2:

                        Console.WriteLine("test2");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        opcion = 0;
                        break;

                }

            }

        }
        static int rdanom(int rd)
        {
            int daño = new Random().Next(1, 13);
            


            return daño;
        }
    }
   
    }
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te da cada error? En todo caso, crear un nuevo objeto Random() para obtener cada número puede dar problemas si el código se repite demasiado rápidamente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77056/por-qu%c3%a9-los-n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-se-repiten-al-llamar-a-next/77061#77061

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te marca que no puedes aplicar la operación resta (`-`) entre un `int` y un método.
`rdanom` es un método por lo que si quieres obtener el valor que devuelve debes invocarlo.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // ...
    nVida = nVida - Random();
}

static int Random()
{
    int damage = new Random().Next(1, 13);
    return damage;
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pude arreglar ^^.